# ER diagram to Relational database PK problem

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have an ER diagram like this:
[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FruGG.png)

I'm having a problem to convert this ER diagram to relational database model. I know that entity should have a primary key to not to be redundant. But I see that G doesn't have a primary key as it has only e.

What should I do? Do you think this ER diagram is faulty?